# jQuery Tree Traversing to select next div

Tags: jquery, jquery-traversing

Looking for a way to accomplish populating a div with jQuery, traversing.. which I'm no good at.

My code has a series of 6 boxes and then a content box.. another 6 boxes and a content box like so:

```
<div class='box'><img src='x' /></div>
<div class='box'><img src='x' /></div>
<div class='box'><img src='x' /></div>
<div class='box'><img src='x' /></div>
<div class='box'><img src='x' /></div>
<div class='box'><img src='x' /></div>
<div class='box'><img src='x' /></div>
<div class='content'></div>
<div class='box'><img src='x' /></div>
<div class='box'><img src='x' /></div>
<div class='box'><img src='x' /></div>
<div class='box'><img src='x' /></div>
<div class='box'><img src='x' /></div>
<div class='box'><img src='x' /></div>
<div class='box'><img src='x' /></div>
<div class='content'></div>
```

What I am looking for is when somebody clicks on the image - it populates the next `.content div` only.

Thanks in advance.

===
For Hugo..
The closest I got, which obviously populates all the content boxes is:

```
$(".box img").click(function(){
                $(this).parent().parent().find(".content").html("X");
            });
```

Comment: Can you show us some part of code you tried? We can help you fix code but won't write you a whole part of code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.box img').click(function(){
   $(this).parent().nextAll('.content').first().text('...');
})
```

Comment: Augh, *44 seconds!* And, obviously, +1.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the appropriate [traversal functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) for this. The "best" version depends on your markup and the relative stability of its various pieces, but for now let's just work with the HTML you give.

Starting from any `<img>`, you want to move up to its parent `.box` and then look for the next `.content`. Translating to jQuery:

```
$(this).parent().nextAll(".content").first()
```

Comment: Thanks for the more thorough explanation Jon - appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img').click(function() {
  var $nextdiv = $(this).parent().nextUntil('.content').addBack().last().next();
  // do something with it
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/gRKfa/

http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil

(`.nextAll().first()` is rather less complicated, though.)